# Query posts by custom taxonomy ID

Tags: query-posts, tax-query

I have a custom post type called `portfolio` and a custom taxonomy called `build-type` (acting as categories)

I am trying to query `portfolio` posts by `build-type` ID e.g. all Portfolio posts in "Hotels" (id=4 for that taxonomy)

```
// gets the ID from a custom field to show posts on a specific page   
$buildType = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'build_type_id', true);
// run query
query_posts(array( 
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'showposts' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'build-type',
        'terms' => $buildType,
        'field' => 'term_id'
    ),
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

Currently it's calling **all** `portfolio` posts and not just those with the `build-type` ID

For `'field' => 'term_id'` should I be using `term_id`, `tag_ID`, `id` or something else?

Anyone know how to get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because 'tax_query' needs to be an array of arrays (confusing, I know).

```
...

'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'build-type',

...
```

It is that way so you can group a few different rules together.

Comment: Nice one Drew. That solved it. Posted the final script on Github https://gist.github.com/1275191

Comment: Cheers! Spent hour from customers budget resolving this minor issue :)

Answer (score 7):

Drew was right, `tax-query` needs to be an array of arrays

The final solution is:

```
// gets the ID from a custom field to show posts on a specific page
$buildType = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'build_type_id', true);
// run query
query_posts(array( 
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'showposts' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'build-type',
            'terms' => $buildType,
            'field' => 'term_id',
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC' )
);
```

On github here:

https://gist.github.com/1275191

Thanks!

Comment: Unaccepting my answer and accepting your own really hurts man... hurts me in my heart. If anybody needs me, I'll be in the lounge.

Comment: Hah sorry dude. I'm new to all this, didn't realise you could only have one answer. I will re-mark it so you can venture back out of the lounge

Comment: Haha man it's alright, I was just joking around - If you want to self-accept an answer its totally allowed, but be sure to Upvote my answer so I at least get some point love.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array inside tax_query where you can also select operators.
For example a print_r of tax_query should look like these.

```
 Array
(
    [relation] => AND
    [0] => Array
        (
            [taxonomy] => build-type
            [terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => term1
                    [1] => term2blabla
                )

            [field] => slug
            [operator] => IN
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [taxonomy] => another-taxonomie
            [terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => term1
                    [1] => term2
                )

            [field] => slug
            [operator] => IN
        )

)
```

Of course you can change the field for id but i always used slugs to keep it simpler.
As you can see you can query multiple taxonomies like these.

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to use the tax_query,remove it and append the following:

`term=>build-type,'build-type=>hotels'` for example.